# How to use JavaScript to generate all numbers divisible by 3 within two numbers specified by the user

Tags: javascript, numbers, range

The title is pretty self-explanatory.

I need to set up JavaScript so that when the user of the webpage inputs two numbers, the output will be all numbers in that range divisible by 3. However, if the first number inputted is higher than the second, then the page will return an alert box saying “invalid range!” I think I have that part down, but that’s about it. How would I go about doing that.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. This sounds like a relatively simple task, and while that doesn't mean there's any shame in struggling with it, there could be a number of things you're doing wrong, and without seeing what code you've tried it would just be guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript offers a powerful operator called **modulo** represented by  **%** which returns the remainder after a division of two numbers.
Conveniently it returns 0 if there is no remainder.
So in your case, if the number x divided by 3 returns 0, it's safe to say it's dividable by 3.
Now everything you need to do is go through all numbers from your first number to your second number, check if there's a remainder after division by 3 and in case there isn't push the number into an array.

Here's a sample:

```
var results = [];
var firstNumber = 200;
var secondNumber = 400;
if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
  console.log("Invalid range")
} else {
  for (a = firstNumber; a < secondNumber; a++) {
    if (a % 3 == 0) {
      results.push(a);
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need!

```js
const num1 = 7;
const num2 = 63;
let output = [];

if (num1 <= num2) {
  for (let i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0)
      output.push(i);
  }
} else {
  alert("invalid range!");
}

console.log(output);
```